# Excel VBA/Macro, move row to another worksheet, values only

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a simple problem I cannot figure out.

Right now I have a macro set up that moves 1 selected row, to the bottom of another worksheet and changes it's color based on good/bad outcome.

I need the **cell values and color formatting** to be copy/pasted to the other worksheet.

Here's the code I have now

```
Sub CloseCasePaid()
'
' CloseCasePaid Macro
'
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -1003520
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Selection.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Closed Files").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Selection.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: `it works so far` so uh what's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, it works in moving the row over to the other sheet, but it doesn't copy the values only. I need it to move the values ONLY.

Comment: Then set the ranges to each other instead of copy/paste.

Comment: How about `Selection.EntireRow.Copy` without the destination and at the next line `Sheets("Closed Files").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial 12`?

Comment: Might consider qualifying `Rows.Count` @DirkReichel

Answer (score 0):

You need to use paste special - values. Here's the syntax:

```
Range("A1").Copy

Range("B2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

I would do this before deleting the row, since deleting the row will knock it out of the clipboard.

Comment: Copy/paste is very slow. If only values are needed, set ranges to each other.

Comment: @findwindow But that excludes also the formatting... you sure he dont need it?

Comment: @DirkReichel per OP `I need it to move the values ONLY` Edit: paste values is fine/works. Just that once you know better, you try to do better ^_^;

Comment: You could also use Range("B2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) if he needs the formatting after you paste the values. If speed is an issue I agree, you could just assign to variables. Excel can automatically construct an array from a range object.

Comment: @findwindow he first changes the color... I assumed he wanted to keep the formatting... <- the OP also want to copy the formatting :D

Comment: @DirkReichel OP is copying from one sheet to another I think. Edit: per OP `need the values to be copy/pasted to the other worksheet`

Comment: @worvolin want to clarify?

Comment: @findwindow I would like the color formatting to be moved along with the values of the cells. This doesn't have to run fast, because I only would be using this a couple times a day max.

Comment: @warvolin Thanks for clarifying. Next time please don't write `I need it to move the values ONLY`

Comment: @findwindow thank you and I will be as clear as possible next time. Also thank you for you super fast responses and answers to my problem. It is appreciated.

Comment: @findwindow I need the color formatting to transfer over yes, but one column in the row has a date formula that displays days old. When transferring this row to the other sheet, I'd like that **value** (days old) to transfer. So far, with my code I can transfer color but not values, with the code examples above I can copy/paste just the values and no color. I don't know how to implement Range into my code, can you explain further? Thanks

Comment: Uhh. That beats me :/ Your code is set to transfer everything and if it does color, it should be values as well....